# Use reflection to invoke method

Tags: c#, system.reflection

While working with Azure ServiceFabric, we are using `StateManager.GetStateAsync` method to get values, The same method can be used to get the value in object type like classes.

I'm trying with below Code

```
var typeObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var method = typeof(IActorStateManager).GetMethod(nameof(IActorStateManager.GetStateAsync));
            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            dynamic task = generic.Invoke(typeObj, new[] { stateName })
            object result = await task;
```

With this approach, I'm getting the exception.

```
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232829
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Object does not match target type."
    Source: "mscorlib"
    StackTrace: "at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
                at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  
                at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   
                at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)"
    TargetSite: {Void CheckConsistency(System.Object)}
```

Comment: IMO, using `catch` without inspecting/logging the error is a horrible way of writing programs.

Comment: I agree that's why refactoring the code with implementing reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, a few things have been confused here. If your code is that what you are actually executing, you are over/misusing the `type` variable.

Let's decide that `type` is a concrete `ActorStateManager`. Then

```
var typeObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // typeobj is now ActorStateManager
```

The error is probably here:

```
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type); 
// generic is now StateManager.GetStateAsync<ActorStateManager>
```

Your intent was not to create `StateManager.GetStateAsync<ActorStateManager>`, but 
`StateManager.GetStateAsync<bool>` or `StateManager.GetStateAsync<DateTime>`.

Additionally, I GetStateAsync [takes an (optional?) cancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstatemanager.getstateasync?view=azure-dotnet) as a second argument, better to be explicit when doing reflection.

So here is what you want to do I guess:

```
    public async Task<object> TryLotsOfTypesAndIgnoreErrors(string stateName)
    {
        var typeObj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ActorStateManager));
        foreach (var typeParam in new[] {typeof(bool), typeof(string)})
        {
            try
            {
                var method = typeof(IActorStateManager).GetMethod(nameof(IActorStateManager.GetStateAsync));
                var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeParam);
                var task = (Task) generic.Invoke(typeObj, new object[] { stateName, CancellationToken.None });
                await task;
                return task.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Task<object>.Result))?.GetValue(task);
            }
            catch
            {
                // TODO: Catch only exception specific to type mismatch
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I intended `type` tobe `typeof(bool)` or `typeof(DateTime)` or `typeof(CUSTOMClass)` so when I pass the type as param for reflection method it should return the the `object result`
I'll try this way and see.

Comment: The generic part of `Task` (`Task.Result`) was missing in my code, see my edit (also, edited so that the code compiles)